# How can I left align the text in the figure/table caption?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

How can I left align the text in the figure/table caption?
This is the text I am using to add an image

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth]{Figures/EdgeYarnA9}
        \caption[abc]{abc}
    \label{fig:EdgeYarnA9}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your document class and relevant packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get used to specifying figures with commands, rather than environments, boxhandler will solve this, assuming you mean left-align to the figure and not the margin.  (It can left align to margin, too, but you don't need boxhandler for just that)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\begin{document}

By default, boxhandler gives this

\bxfigure[ht]{This is the caption which, by default is idented wrt the
figure identifier}
{\rule{3in}{2in}}

But by changing the caption style with \verb|\captionStyle{n}{l}|, one
gets the following:

\captionStyle{n}{l}

\bxfigure[ht]{This is the caption which, by default is idented wrt the
figure identifier}
{\rule{3in}{2in}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A caveat in using the boxhandler environment is that it doesn't allow for including a sub-caption. For example, I got into the situation of needing a main caption centered above the figure, and another one below it and left-aligned to the picture.

Although it's not the state-of-the-art solution, I managed to find a workaround for it using a minipage environment inside the figure environment:

```
\begin{figure}[h] \label{fig:caption-example}
    \caption{Example figure}
    \vspace*{6pt}
    \centering  \includegraphics{MyPicture.png} \par
    \begin{minipage}[h]{8cm}
        \footnotesize
        Source: the Author (2018)
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The solution for the proper alignment was finetuning the minipage's width to match the figure's width.

Comment: You can store the figure width an reuse it in the minipage. See e.g. my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422360/2975

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for the tip, it worked just fine! Just had to use a \raggedleft command in the text content of the \adjustbox command argument.