# How to set width of caption to width of figure?

Tags: floats, captions

How can I set the width of the caption to be the same as the width of the pic when I give a height of a picture and have the width deduced automatically by aspect ratio?

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[height=10cm]{pic.png}
  \caption{My very long caption ....}
\end{figure}
```

In this case the pic is on the left (let's assume only 12cm wide) and the caption is running over the complete text width.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to store the image in a savebox and then wrap the caption into a minipage with the width of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\mysavebox

\usepackage{lipsum} % for example text only
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \sbox\mysavebox{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}}%
  \usebox\mysavebox
  \par
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\mysavebox}
  \caption{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long caption }
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The `adjustbox` package simplifies this approach and also avoids "bad box" warnings if the image is larger then the usual text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newlength\mylength

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\adjustimage{height=5cm, gstore width=\mylength, center}{example-image}
%alternative: \adjustbox{gstore width=\mylength,center}{\includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image}}
\par% or empty line, needed to get caption below the image, not to the rigth
\adjustbox{minipage=\mylength,center}{\caption{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long caption }}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Martin, out of curiosity: would this approach work for a `tabular` too?

Comment: It should, as tabular creates a TeX box that can be put in a savebox.

Comment: That's very nice. I'd been looking for something like this. Thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs: This works with all content. If there are multiple paragraphs the content needs to be wrapped in a `minipage` environment beforehand. With `\begin{adjustbox}{height=10cm}\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}\end{adjustbox}` you could even scale the `tabular` or any other content. However, scaling text is discouraged as the font might not be good readable when scaled. Different font sizes use different letter designs for this.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Great.

Comment: If I now have a \begin{multicols}{3} ... \end{multicols} document, how can I use the above solution to get a figure let's say inlined in a 3 column paper strechting over 2 columns?

If directly used I get a "Latex error: Not in outer par mode." - I know this is related to figures being float... but what now?

Comment: @RobertM.Münch: Not sure if I understand the case, but if you have paragraph material inside a box you need to wrap it with a `minipage` or `varwidth` environment, i.e. use `\adjustbox{varwidth...}` etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer The case is: If I want to use your solution inside a \begin{multicols}{3} ... \end{multicols} section, it's not working at the moment. It would be great to span the figure over 2 of the 3 columns.

Answer (score 4):

There are two other solutions: with the `measuredfigure` environment, from `threeparttable`, and  the `\ffigbox` command from `floatrow`; use asoptional argument `\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{image}{caption}`. One advantage is that if you want the caption to be only a little wider than the figure width, you just have to change`[\FBwidth]` to, say, `[1.25\FBwidth]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable, floatrow}
\newsavebox\mysavebox

\usepackage{lipsum} %
\begin{document}
%
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\begin{measuredfigure} \centering
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
 \caption{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long caption }
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure} \centering
\ffigbox[1.25\FBwidth]%
{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}}
 { \caption{My very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long caption }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the `\newsavebox\mysavebox` commands relevant to `floatrow`, `threeparttable` or both?

Comment: I have no idea. These packages measure the figures/tables they enclose (threeparttable defines a `measuredfigure` environment)