# Obtaining different caption widths for different picture widths

Tags: captions, minipage

I am trying to make some nice-looking captions for some photos.  The problem is that when I keep the aspect ratio unchanged, the picture widths will be different and I have only been able to figure out how to declare a *single* caption width (and not several that adjust to each picture width).

A working example (whether or not it is *minimal*, I do not know) follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%\graphicspath{{/Users/...} (!NOTE! will not compile unless (1) your own graphics path is declared and (2) examplePhoto1 and examplePhoto2 names are suitably renamed)


\definecolor{captionColor}{RGB}{103,143,150}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{customCaption}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    nobeforeafter,
    colback=captionColor,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    colupper=white,
    %fontupper=\normal,
    boxsep=0pt
  ]
  #1#2#3
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\captionsetup{format=customCaption,labelformat=empty,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,position=bottom,skip=0pt,textfont={it}}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}

\begin{document}

The beginning of the document stretches the full text width.
\vspace{15mm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.60\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
There will be some text on the left side of the page.  The start of this text needs to be vertically aligned with the top of the other minipage.
\end{minipage}
\quad \quad \quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{examplePhoto1}
{\caption[]{Caption to first picture}}
\vspace{6mm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{examplePhoto2}
{\caption[]{Caption to second picture (which will probably not be the same width as the first picture)}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And more or less the same solutions in another question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422359/how-to-set-width-of-caption-to-width-of-figure

Comment: Another approach is to use an individual minipage for each figure as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166721/

Comment: And there is also the [boxhandler](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/boxhandler/boxhandler.pdf) package for this kind of functionality.